# weird problem. adding 1 to 0 doesnt do anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1Okay, i dont even know how to describe this problem but i will try my best. you can find all my code at the bottom

```
 const scores = { 0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0 }
 const [point, setPoint] = useState(scores)
```

so i setstate to an array, later on i am calling it with a button

```
 <button onClick ={()=> setPoint (point[selected] +1 )}>Vote</button>
 <button onClick={()=> setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random()* anecdotes.length ))}>next anecdotes</button>
 {scores[selected]}
```

at first it should the value at the [selected] to be at 0, but whenever i press on the vote button and add 1, it is still 0. i just wonder if anyone can help with this.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const anecdotes = [
    'If it hurts, do it more often',
    'Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!',
    'The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 10 percent of the development time...The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.',
    'Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.',
    'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.',
    'Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.',
    'Programming without an extremely heavy use of console.log is same as if a doctor would refuse to use x-rays or blood tests when diagnosing patients'
  ]
   
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0) 
  const scores = { 0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0 }
  const [point, setPoint] = useState(scores)
  
  return (
    console.log (selected),
    console.log (point[selected]),
    <div>
      {anecdotes[selected]}
      <br></br>
      <button onClick ={()=> setPoint (point[selected] +1 )}>Vote</button>
      <button onClick={()=> setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random()* anecdotes.length ))}>next anecdotes</button>
      {point[selected]}

    </div>
  )
}
/*onst Set = (...[points, selected]) => {
  points [selected] += 1;
  console.log(points [selected]);
<h1>{points}</h1>
}*/

export default App
```

Comment: i've tried both point[selected] and scores[selected]

Comment: Did you checkout the answer I gave below, does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think `setPoint (point[selected] +1 )` is replacing your state with a number, instead of updating the object (which was the initial state of `scores`).  I think you may need to do something like ...

```
   const updatedValue = point[selected] + 1;
   setPoint({...point, [selected]: updatedValue})
```

Comment: It is poor practice to update state that is dependent on previous state in this manner as state updates are asynchronous. The useState updater function should be used in this case to ensure the most recent state snapshot is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Update the logic for updating the `points` state as shown below:

```js
const anecdotes = [
  "If it hurts, do it more often",
  "Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!",
  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil.",
];

const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(0);
  const [points, setPoints] = React.useState({ 0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0 });

  return (
    <div>
      {anecdotes[selected]}
      <br></br>
      <button onClick={() => setPoints({ ...points, [selected]: points[selected] + 1 })}>
        Vote
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random() * anecdotes.length))}>
        Next Anecdote
      </button>
      {points[selected]}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Also, there's no need for a separate `scores` variable and you can also move the `anecdotes` array outside the component.

*Note: I've reduced the no. of anecdotes so that you can quickly see the votes working.*

**Bonus Tip:**

Currently your random selection can pick up the same anecdote that is currently selected, which means nothing happens on that button click, which is not a very good user experience.

Checkout the snippet below where every time you click on the "Next Anecdote" button, it guarantees a new anecdote.

```js
const anecdotes = [
  "If it hurts, do it more often",
  "Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!",
  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil.",
];

const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(0);
  const [points, setPoints] = React.useState({ 0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0 });

  const getNextAnecdote = () => {
    const choosableIndicies = anecdotes.map((_, i) => i).filter((i) => i !== selected);
    setSelected(choosableIndicies[Math.floor(Math.random() * choosableIndicies.length)]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {anecdotes[selected]}
      <br></br>
      <button onClick={() => setPoints({ ...points, [selected]: points[selected] + 1 })}>
        Vote
      </button>
      <button onClick={getNextAnecdote}>Next Anecdote</button>
      {points[selected]}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Updating state that is dependent on previous state should be achieved using the functional updates pattern, given state updates are performed asynchronously.

Comment: @Ben That is not a necessity, that depends on the context. There's no general rule of thumb as such.

Comment: Of course it's not a necessity. Updating state without the updater function will work in most cases. However, it's certainly best practice to use it, particularly when updating objects. As the project grows and state updates become more frequent, the probability of a bug originating from this issue becomes more likely.

Comment: If you want to be on the safer side always use an updater function but if you understand how your updates work, you would be able to distinguish when it's required and when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update state like that if the variable is an object. You should access the most recent previous state snapshot using the updater function, then update the variable, and return the new state.

```
setPoint(state => {
  
  return { ...state, [selected]: state[selected] + 1 }

})
```

or

```
setPoint(state => {
  
  state[selected]++

  return state

})
```

**Using the updater function ensures you access the most recent state snapshot. Simply using `setPoints({ ...points, [selected]: points[selected] + 1 })}` does not guarantee the most recent state will be accessed.**